# Error when building Redhawk Device - inherited pure virtual method

Tags: redhawksdr

I am building a Redhawk Device using Redhawk 1.9 on Centos 5.3. (Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 21 10:44:23 EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux)

1.) When I compile the Redhawk device, I am getting the following error:

"The type 'bulkio::InPort' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'omniServant::_do_get_interface'"

AR8200Device_base.cpp - line 48

```
PortableServer::ObjectId_var oid;
command = new bulkio::InCharPort("command");
```

2.) I also get a warning:
‘class bulkio::InSDDSPort::Callback’ has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
line 60, external location: /usr/local/redhawk/core/include/bulkio/bulkio_sdds.h    C/C++ Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these issues should not get in your way of building and deploying your device.  For item #1 I have see it where Eclipse reports it as an error but that the build completed successfully.  Is this what you are seeing?  The problem is actually just that Eclipse's CDT plugin is highlighting and error that is not actually there.  They have a known bug with this issue against CDT.  If you check the console output you should see that your device did build without error and can be deployed.  As for the second item, I believe this is a warning against some of the code that the device is linking against, but in this case will not cause any harm.  Try to deploy and run your device despite these two messages and I believe it will work.

Comment: I did deploy the component and disregard the errors. It worked as expected.